# edit mode (wire) renders different than object wire frame mode in blender 2.7.9

Tags: wireframe

Someone else must have asked this but I'm not searching the right phrase or words to get at it/them.

I'm extruding plane edges from a 4 point plane to create a mesh, and I extrude one or more edges at a time.  There is a shrinkwrap and mirror modifier applied to this geometry.  The attached shows my object renders all valid faces in edit mode, but in object mode it looks like some interior faces might be invalid or missing.  Some of the interior edges 'skip'.

I have tried selecting all edges in edit mode and removing doubles (no impact).

Is this something to worry about?  The face count blender shows me in edit is right (24 total faces).

A shows the object mode, B is edit.

[image: object display vs edit mode display]

Thx

Comment: Have you added any modifier to the mesh ?